# How trigger event in input fields?

Tags: jquery, bpmn.io

I'm trying to update the value in **Input Parameter**- Name , using jquery :

```
$("#camunda-parameterName").val('Single2');
```

it's working change value , but not reflect in all fields.

in the happy senario when update the using keyboard the value reflect in all filed.

the below screen in happy scenario user enter name :

[image]

but when using jquery the input field updated but not all fields reflect this change: 
[image]

[image]

i trying below command but not working :

```
$("#camunda-parameterName").val('Single2').change();
$("#camunda-parameterName").trigger('focus')
$("#camunda-parameterName").trigger('blur');
$("#camunda-parameterName").trigger('input');
$("#camunda-parameterName").change();
```

Comment: so i think the input field in Input Pratemeter -> Name is with the ID "amunda-parameterName"? the same ID can only be used on one field per site, so if you just change the value of this ID its normal that the rest is not updated.. you need to update the field above too

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
$("#yourfield").on("keyup", function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $(".yourfield2").text(val);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>You have to have an ID or a Class (if you want to populate on multiple spots) everywhere you want to change the text</p>
<input type="text" name="yourfield" id="yourfield"><br>
<p class="yourfield2">Your Text will be display here</p>
<p class="yourfield2">and here</p>
```

hope you understand what i mean and can use it in your project!

Answer (score 0):

```
evt = new MouseEvent(('change'), {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });

document.getElementByID('camunda-parameterName"').dispatchEvent(evt);
```